# Initialization priority in verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Hello verilog experts,

In the verilog code below, can I be 100% that `top.test.p` will be systematically initialized to 200?

Or will I have a race between the variable initialization and the initial statement? In other words, some simulators will give me `top.test.p == 100` and others `top.test.p == 200`?

Thanks

```
    module test;
       parameter real P = 1e3;
       real P=p;
    endmodule    

    module top;
      test #(100) test();
      initial
       begin
       // override the variable initialization (race condition????)
       test.p = 200;
      end
    endmodule
```

Comment: Do you mean _parameter_ by `parameter real P = 1e3`? I guess it must be `p` instead of `P` (can be typo mistake), also it must be variable, not a parameter. Parameters can not be changed in procedural block, they can only be over-ridden while instantiating or by `defparam`.

Answer (score 3):

A SystemVerilog compliant simulator must execute variable declaration initialization before any initial or always process begins. So top.test.p should be 200

Section 6.8 says

> Setting the initial value of a static variable as part of the variable
>   declaration (including static class members) shall occur before any
>   initial or always procedures are started (also see 6.21 and 10.5 on
>   variable initialization with static and automatic lifetimes).

This ordering was undefined in Verilog.